# Unwanted characters predicted instead of blank/no label in CNN-RNN-CTC network for Word Recognition

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, ocr

I am training a **CNN-RNN-CTC** network for predicting a word in an image. Accuracy (edit distance - 0) is around 75-80%.

One of the problems I have encountered from the beginning is the prediction of unwanted characters in place of a no label (blank label as mentioned in CTC) either at the start or at the end of an image.

For example, an image containing the word "**Hello**" might be predicted as "**IHello**" or "l**Hello**" or "**Helloi**". This error varies for every epoch (each epoch might introduce a different character - '**_**' for one and '**I**' for another. Hence I am forced to choose a model with the least error insertion rate.

Can anyone help me try to find what's going wrong??

The implementation I have used is : https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/image_ocr.py

**LINKS TO IMAGES below**

[Prediction for this image is **13.22** instead of **3.22**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FP8P.png)

[**IADYAR** instead of **ADYAR**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJW2k.png)

Comment: there is no reason why a wrong character occurs exactly at the beginning or end of a word (if the rest of the image is "empty", e.g. white background). Either (a) the model is not yet fully trained or (b) the model does not have enough capacity to learn your task. In case (a) keep on training while in case (b) have a look at e.g. the CRNN implementation, which yields good results for common HTR datasets such as IAM.

Comment: @Harry Thanks for your response.(b) I am already using CRNN implementation for text recognition as mentioned above. (a) Model seems to be saturated after 5 - 10 epochs.Guess I should use a much more powerful network for better learning.

Comment: could you show a sample image for which the problem occurs? Is your dataset much more complex than IAM?

Comment: I have attached links to images above.These images are not complex enough, yet extra characters are included. I get the same prediction even for binarized versions of these images(thought grayscale data could be an issue here). Regarding dataset, there are no handwritten characters, words are written using a wide range of fonts on different backgrounds(includes blur, rotation, elastic distortion).

Comment: I have the exactly same problem here, btw do you have added the " " to your model ?